# Where do I find the more sophisticated "start debugging" submenu in the Visual Studio customize toolbars dialog?

Tags: visual-studio, customization

In Visual Studio in Tools > Customize > Commands > Add Command, I can add nearly any command or submenu to any menubar or toolbar.

For example, to add the simple "start debugging" play button, I choose the command Debug > "Start / Continue".

[image]

In Add Command, where do I find the more sophisticated "start debugging" submenu shown below, so that I can add it to a custom menu bar or toolbar?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to run a vs studio repair? C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe -> then repair whatever version is installed, it takes couple of minutes, that you should have it in the toolbar selection "Debug"

Answer (score 1):

> The Debug toolbar button is a split button and is "special" since the debug targets which are added to the toolbar are done programmatically. You cannot add new debug targets through the toolbar. Those can only be added by project systems and/or extensions to Visual Studio.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/start-debug-target-command-is-not-a-drop-down/555333

Seems like but bug but Microsoft closed it as not a bug.

Comment: So once I remove it from my toolbar, there's no way to put it back?  I don't want to add new debug targets, I just want the whole button back.

Answer (score 0):

Press F5 (Debug > Start Debugging) or the Start Debugging button Start Debugging in the Debug Toolbar, and the debugger runs to the first breakpoint that it encounters. If the app is not yet running, F5 starts the debugger and stops at the first breakpoint.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-customize-menus-and-toolbars-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

first link is to find out debugger and second is for adding it in tool bar